# wordpress settings API and option array structure

Tags: settings-api

how do you get the settings API to save options that are in an array structure like this:

```
$array = array (
                array(
             'id'=> '1',
             'name'=> 'tom',
             'pageurl'=> 'someurl',
             'notes'=> 'someNotes'
              )
                array(
                 'id'=>'2',
                 'name'=>'harry',
                 'pageurl'=>'someotherurl',
                 'notes'=>'anothernote'
                  ) 
          );
```

This array gets data sets added to and deleted from it by the user.  The wp_list_table class I am using had its option set up the same way and I need to be able to edit those values later without having to delete the whole data set of the array I need to change and then recreating it.
I have tried presscoders example and ozh sample options solutions with no success. I am trying to update the name field in the array of arrays.  Only reason I am using this array structure is because of the wp list table.

About to pull my hair out trying to get this to work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'ozh_sampleoptions_init' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'ozh_sampleoptions_add_page');

// Init plugin options to white list our options
function ozh_sampleoptions_init(){
    register_setting( 'ozh_sampleoptions_options', 'fp_options', 'ozh_sampleoptions_validate' );
}

// Add menu page
function ozh_sampleoptions_add_page() {
    add_options_page('Ozh\'s Sample Options', 'Sample Options', 'manage_options', 'ozh_sampleoptions', 'ozh_sampleoptions_do_page');
}

// Draw the menu page itself
function ozh_sampleoptions_do_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Ozh's Sample Options</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('ozh_sampleoptions_options'); ?>
            <?php $options = get_option('fp_options'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">

                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row">Tab Name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ozh_sample[name]" size="75" value="<?php echo $options[0]['name']; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php   
}

// Sanitize and validate input. Accepts an array, return a sanitized array.
function ozh_sampleoptions_validate($input) {

    // Say our option must be safe text with no HTML tags
    $input[0]['name'] =  wp_filter_nohtml_kses($input['name']);

    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What data are you trying to save as an array, and *why* do those data need to be saved as an array?

Comment: I am saving an, id, name, url, and personal notes in an array of arrays as shown above.  The option is being saved in the wp_options table, when created by another part of my plugin.  I need an options page to enable the user to change the data at will, but i can't get the settings API to save the changes.  The option will store multiple arrays with data for different pages and urls.

Comment: I understand that, but the important part of the question is: *why* do these data need to be in their own array?

Comment: because that is how the wp_list_table class stores them and I am using that class to add new data set arrays to the option table and they need to match the same structure.

Comment: If I can figure out how to update one field then the rest will be easy

Answer (score 2):

The Settings API generally expects data in the `key => value` form. I'm sure it is *possible* to save array data using the Settings API, but it somewhat circumvents the purpose of the API.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to take a **Plugin Option**, and use the value of that option to update the `wp_list_table` class. The most straightforward approach might be to save some unique key as the Plugin option, and then cross-reference that unique key against a *separate* array-of-arrays to use to extend `wp_list_table`.

In other words, build your `wp_list_table` values array, perhaps like so:

```
<?php
function plugin_slug_get_wp_list_table_data() {
    $data = array(
        'a' = array(
            'id'=> '1',
            'name'=> 'tom',
            'pageurl'=> 'someurl',
            'notes'=> 'someNotes'
        ),
        'b' = array(
            'id'=> '1',
            'name'=> 'tom',
            'pageurl'=> 'someurl',
            'notes'=> 'someNotes'
        ),
        'c' = array(
            'id'=> '1',
            'name'=> 'tom',
            'pageurl'=> 'someurl',
            'notes'=> 'someNotes'
        ),
        'd' = array(
            'id'=> '1',
            'name'=> 'tom',
            'pageurl'=> 'someurl',
            'notes'=> 'someNotes'
        ),
    );
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Then, save your Plugin option as `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, or `'d'`.

Then, get your option:

```
<?php
$plugin_slug_options = get_option( 'plugin_slug_options' );
$plugin_slug_wp_list_table_setting = $plugin_slug_options['wp_list_table_setting'];
?>
```

Then, use the option setting to get the data with which to update `wp_list_table`:

```
<?php
$plugin_slug_wp_list_table_array = plugin_slug_get_wp_list_table_data();
$plugin_slug_wp_list_table_data = $plugin_slug_wp_list_table_array[$plugin_slug_wp_list_table_setting];
?>
```

(How you actually perform the `wp_list_table` update is up to you...)

Comment: Admittedly, a unique key would have been easier to deal with instead of an array of indexed arrays, but the wp_list_table class is not the only part of the plugin that uses that data.  the data array I have shown here is one of 3, all referenced by the id field.